# How to hide div in one css file but show it in another css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I have a basic front end auth login react component page that loads when the page is first rendered.
upon successful login:

- it renders the app component.
- I have a login.css file and a app.css file.
- in my html document i had to add code for a form to submit some user input for the app side of things. I do not want this form to appear on the login side of things just once the app side has rendered.
- On the div classname I have tried `visibility hidden` in `login.css` and `visibility:visible` in `app.css`.
- I have tried `opacity:0` in login.css and `opacity:100` in app.css. as well as some other trouble shooting css that didn't work.
- It appears the `login.css` is overriding the `app.css` no matter what.

I am new to this so sorry if this is a dumb question just really need some help thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use conditional rendering in React for this kind of scenarios, not css. If you are using router, use location pathname to conditional render only if you're not in Login route.

Answer (score 0):

To directly address your question, the CSS property you want to be using is `display` and set it to `none`. If that still doesn't seem to work, check the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your selector and verify that you're selecting the intended element. As a last resort use `!important` in your attribute to override all styles.

Since you're using React though, I highly recommend that you don't depend on CSS for this but rather use conditional rendering, e.g.

```
return (
  <div>
    {loggedIn ? (
      User dashboard or whatever...
    ) : (
      Display login form
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: i tried display none as well originally. The important flag doesnt work bc it overrides it in login css file and shows it on log in render

Comment: I will try out the conditional rendering thank you